# opening a text file on python on a mac

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying to write a program on python on mac,  that allows users to search a database. Im having trouble to open,find or read the text file that is attached.

I have used:

```
import os
with open('a3-example-data.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
            f.seek(0)
            f.readline()
            for line in f:
                if 'Time Taken' in line:
                    print line
                    print ' '.join(line.split())
f.close()
```

and

```
import os
file = open("/Users/moniv/Downloads/a3-example-data(2).txt", "r" "utf8")
```

But keep getting an error message. Please help me :(

Comment: This error message, what is it? Also, I'm not sure why you thought the second snippet would even work, it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

your code is flawed in many parts, and my guess is that the error comes when you're getting back to the main iteration, whereas you seeked back to `0`, making the main iteration unsynced.

```
# you do not need the os module in your code. Useless import
import os

with open('a3-example-data.txt', 'r') as f:
    ### the f.readline() is only making you skip the first line.
    ### Are you doing it on purpose?
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
            ### seeking back to zero,
            f.seek(0)
            ### skipping a line
            f.readline()
            ### iterating over the file again, 
            ### while shadowing the current iteration
            for line in f:
                if 'Time Taken' in line:
                    print line
                    print ' '.join(line.split()) # why are you joining what you just split?
       ### and returning to the main iteration which will get broken
       ### because of the seek(0) within
       ### does not make much sense.

### you're using the context manager, so once you exit the `with` block, the file is closed
### no need to double close it!
f.close()
```

so without understanding what you aim to do, here's my take on your algorithm:

```
import os
with open('a3-example-data.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
            break
    f.seek(0)
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
         if 'Time Taken' in line:
             print line
```